# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value, Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, api, post, ionic-framework

Hi i'm just new to API making and using, i'm using Laravel as for the api part and using angular's HttpClient to make the request, here's the code

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class ApitestProvider {
  tests;
  apiUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api";
  testAdded;
  testGotten;
  testDeleted;
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {

    console.log('Hello ApitestProvider Provider');
  }

  addTest(data) {
    /*let nData= JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(nData);*/
    let obj = {name : "test"};
    this.http.post(this.apiUrl + "/tests",JSON.stringify(obj))
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.testAdded = res;
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

the code its modified for testing purposes, and here is my laravel code for the controller

```
public function store(Request $request){
    return Testme::create($request->all());
}
```

and here is the code for the initial migration

```
class CreateTestmesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('testmes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('testmes');
    }
}
```

also in the model the only fillable is 'name', thanks in advance.

Comment: Try debugging the result, add `dd($request->all());` on the first line of your `store()` function.

Comment: ill do, where im i supposed to see the results tho

Comment: The developer tools in your browser. How did you find the error?

Comment: i just did, it seems it blocked the msg, showed this Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tests. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

Comment: Open your app/middlware/kernal.php file and comment out this line:  \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class Only do this for testing purposes.

Comment: i did, it keeps giving the same warning

Comment: Its preety clear your name field doesnt have default value or buolable on your schema and you are passing empty value on your name

Comment: yeah, i know, but why does it ask for a default value for name, if im sending it in the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, i just had to set the headers for the data format in the request i was sending

just had to use httpheaders

```
  addTest(data) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    let nData = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(nData)
    this.http.post(this.apiUrl + "/tests", nData, {headers: headers})
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.testAdded = res;
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the error says: "Field name doesn't have a default value".
This means that you're not sending any value for this field in your post request.
So you have three ways:

1 -> fill the name field with a value in the client http request

2 -> go to the database user's migration inside laravel application and set a default value to the name field, like this: **$table->string('name')->default('');**

3 -> go to the same file of 2° point and set name field nullable like this: **$table->string('name')->nullable();**

Comment: thats were the issue lies, in 1, you can see that im sending the "name" value in the post request, why is the api not getting it?

Comment: Check your mass assignement attributes inside model and try with $request->name or just make an insert like DB::table(‘testmes’)->insert([ “name” => $request->name ]);